# Should I downgrade Node.js version to install Mailjet?

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs

The Mailjet library requires Node.js version 4.0, 4.1, 5.0.0 or 6.11.1. I'm using it to send emails from a website to a googlemail account.

I'm currently using v14.16.1 so it seems like a massive downgrade, and I'm not sure of the consequences in terms of security or how my code works. (My code is incredibly basic, with pretty much just EJS and Express, since I'm fairly new to development).

Should I downgrade? If so will it break the code if I upgrade again later?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It isn't maintained anymore, please refer to this issue: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-nodejs/issues/95

It becomes very dangerous to use it. I'm still surprised people think it's a good idea to use such old module, there were 34682 downloads the last 7days.

**You shouldn't ever downgrade a nodejs version to use a module.** Especially for deprecated version like v6.